# Does this PHP code look secure for a login system?

Tags: php, security, authentication

This is only part of it, but it is first making the connection, then checking to see if the username exists, then inserting the data into a table.
I don't really know much about PHP, so there is no need to rip into me. Just trying to learn here, and I am wondering if I am on the right track.

```
require("constants.php");
try {  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $dbconnect, $dbpass);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );    
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "sorry, something happened. try going back and try again.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
}  

function checkName(){
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    if($username != $row->username){
    $check = 1;
    }
    else{
    $check = 0;
    }
    return $check;
}
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
function register(){
$check = checkName();
if($check == 1){
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = sha1($salt . $hash);
$data = array($username, $hash, $salt, $ip);
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, ip) values (?, ?, ?)");
$STH->execute($data);
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping through all the users in the database checking if the `username` is taken, I'd just `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = $username` and if a result is returned, you know it has been taken.

Comment: "I don't really know much about PHP" in relation to writing a login system is why those new to software development should not write login systems.  Writing a login system is a topic rife with security pitfalls that only a well-seasoned software developer can really comprehend.  Not only are new programmers learning the basics of a programming language, they also have to simultaneously comprehend complex security issues.  New programmers should use systems written by others who actually know what they are doing (e.g. Barebones SSO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not secure / well-written. It assumes that register globals is enabled, and using global variables in place of function arguments makes the code very hard to port to different contexts. Leaving aside the bad formatting, the complete absence of any comments makes maintenance of the code difficult - good coding style is a pre-requisite to good programming - and hence security.

There are also specific problems with the code itself. It assumes that $username is quoted, will run inefficiently. And since you compare the $username string with what is returned by the database, it's obviously not escaped properly, implying that the code is open to injection attacks. Since you're using PDO, the solution is to simply use a prepared statement / variable binding - which you have actually done with the INSERT!

Iterating through every matching username does not make any sense and seriously undermines the behaviour. A better approach (but not the right one) would be:

```
/**
 * @param username string - a candidate username
 * @param DBH - connected PDO object referencing user database
 * @return bool - true if username does not exist already
 *
 * search the current list of users to see if the candidate username is available
 */
function checkName($username, $DBH){      
  $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
  $STH->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
  $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $row = $STH->fetch();
  if ($row === false) {
     die('whoops!');
  }
  return $username!==$row->username;
}
```

The right solution: Assuming your usernames are unique (and they really, REALLY should be), then don't bother checking if the username exists before the INSERT - create a unique index and check for duplicate key failures after the INSERT.

Next, you use try/catch around the initial connection but do no error checking on the subsequent query. Having caught the exception, although you record and report an error you don't seem to address the flow of control at this point to prevent the rest of the code executing.

Sorry - it's not good code, let alone secure.

Answer (score 7):

1. You do not define $username, and you use it in a single quoted string, so there's no way the SELECT query will execute
2. You should use a prepared statement and bind the username to a parameter in the SELECT query, rather than stick the username directly into a string
3. You do not need to select the user having that username to see if it's already in use, you only need to select the count and see if it's non-zero
4. If your SELECT query returns no rows, your `checkName` function does not return any value since you only return within the loop through the rows

I hope those comments are useful.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [prepared statements](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), instead of inline variables
2. Stop using global variables. Use `$_POST['name']` instead.
3. `if($username != $row->username){` what??!?! Since username is unique - it can be either 1 correct row (always correct) or 0 rows.

Comment: I like how you say not to use globals, then immediately suggest a **super** global. You're absolutely right, of course, but I enjoyed the juxtaposition.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: hehe ;-) Php does not provide any other way to access the request data. If php had any entry point out of the box and request object - I would suggest them then ;-)

Comment: I know, I just found it funny. I did say you were absolutely right :)

Comment: @AgentConundrum: I know you know :-) Indeed it is funny. I commented just for less experienced people if they will read your comment in the future. Just an explanation what you meant.